# elementary OS Freya won't boot

Tags: boot, uefi, elementary-os

I have been trying to boot elementary OS Freya beta 2 to my windows 8 UEFI laptop. I have tried using different wifi networks to download the OS on different computer with different ISO to USB burning apps but no success yet. It will start to boot when I hit install but then it goes black and stops working. Any ideas? I have tried it with and without secure boot. By the way, it an Asus k200ma.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I can help you.
Instead of pressing the enter-key on "install elementary" press the e-key to edit the code. When the code comes up you will see a line of code that has the words "quiet splash" written. On the end of that line write: nomodeset xforcevesa , and then press the f10-key.